Flutter: Google Mobile Ads - Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine
Flutter: Google Mobile Ads - Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine
No matter what I do, I always get code 0 on the device and code 3 on the emulator. I focused the testing on the device so I could try to understand the error I'm getting. I'm trying to display at least the test one, but without success.
E/chromium(26719): [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(154)] Renderer process (27080) crash detected (code -1).
I/Ads     (26719): Ad failed to load : 0
I/flutter (26719): error: LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})
Below is what I tried to do to make it work.
I've tried several approaches and followed some tutorials, but I always get the same error.
google_mobile_ads: ^5.1.0
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();

  // thing to add
  RequestConfiguration configuration = RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: deviceIds);
  MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(configuration);

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

 loadAd() {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111', // adUnitId banner test
      request: const AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          debugPrint('$ad loaded.');
          setState(() {
            _isLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          debugPrint('BannerAd failed to load: $err');
          ad.dispose();
        },
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) {},
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) {},
        onAdImpression: (Ad ad) {},
      ),
    )..load();
  }

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.admob"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.admob"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
       
        // minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion 21
       
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.0.0'
}


Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

You probably have a proxy or ad blocker set up.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
